# Ionic Angular nbOnInit Undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem with Ionic. I want to put number of page in the function in ngOnInit but is writing undefined

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpConfigService } from '../services/http-config.service';
import { GeolocationService } from '../services/geolocation.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-commerces',
  templateUrl: './commerces.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./commerces.page.scss'],
})
export class CommercesPage implements OnInit {

  url: string;
  itemListData = [];
  page_number = 1;
  page_limit = 8;
  isFinish = false;
  nbPages;

  constructor(
    private httpConfigService: HttpConfigService,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private geolocationService: GeolocationService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nbPages();
    this.getCommerces(true, "");
  }

  doInfinite(event) {
    this.nbPages();
    this.getCommerces(true, event);
  }

  sort() {
    this.itemListData.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.title.rendered > b.title.rendered) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a.title.rendered < b.title.rendered) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }

  onSearchChange(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.value);
  }


  npPage() {
    this.httpClient
      .get('https://exemple.fr/wp-json/wp/v2/listing', { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        // Here, resp is of type HttpResponse<MyJsonData>.
        // You can inspect its headers:
        this.nbPages = data.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages');
      });
  }

  getCommerces(isFirstLoad, event) {
    for (let j = 1; j < this.nbPages; j++) {
      this.httpClient
        .get('https://exemple.fr/wp-json/wp/v2/listing?page=' + j, { observe: 'response' })
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.body.length; i++) {
            data.body[i].location = this.geolocationService.getDistance(data.body[i]._geolocation_lat, data.body[i]._geolocation_long).toFixed(2);;
            data.body[i]._gallery = data.body[i]._gallery[Object.keys(data.body[i]._gallery)[0]]
            this.itemListData.push(data.body[i]);
          }

          if (isFirstLoad)
            event.target.complete();

        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
    }
    this.sort();
    console.log(this.itemListData);
  }
}
```

nbPages is undefined and I need this variable to do the loop for in getCommerces()

Can you help me find where is the problem, Angular for me is new, It's not possible in ngOnInit to change value of variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implements OnInit on your class definition:

```
export class YOURCLASSNAME implements OnInit {
```

You are calling a function :
nbPages()

but your function is defined as : (without the final s)

```
npPage() {
```

Comment: You need to share more code cause some elements are missing

Comment: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.nbPages is not a function
TypeError: this.nbPages is not a function` 
It's my error now

Comment: Read my response :

you must call "npPage()" not nbPages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221398/discussion-between-rmarquet21-and-raphael-st).